# Book recommendation on mammal (or just primate) behaviour, especially in relation to child-rearing

Tags: ethology, behaviour, mammals, book-recommendation, psychology

I have a growing frustration with the lows 'new-age' parenting is reaching, along with asininity of so much of our public schools' (and summer camps') philosophies and policies in relation to our kids. Whatever the implications, this has continually lead me to the thought of

> what the *natural precedent* is for how primates (or other mammals) raise their young, collectively or otherwise -- how they're guided, rewarded, chastised, and conditioned.

May someone please recommend a book that delves in to some of this? (Humans don't necessarily have to enter the picture, but something that does compare and contrast with the human condition would be a bonus.) (Preferably not a text book, but, by all means, please recommend those too.)

Comment: Please don't fall into the other new age fallacy that states that natural == good. Rape is perfectly natural for example (just look at cats) as is incest (most mammals) and war (chimps for example). That something is 'natural' or the way it is done by a different primate in the wild is no indication that is is a good approach for raising the young of our species. It might be, just not always.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested Reads:

### Evolutionary Psychology

By Lance Workman, Will Reader

### Evolution of Human Behavior: Primate Models

edited by Warren G. Kinzey

### Social Behaviour of Children: A Cross Cultural Assessment

By Ralph E. S. Tanner